# How can I test method which throws NullPointerException using JUnit 5

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, nullpointerexception, junit5

How can I test method which throws NullPointerException using JUnit 5. But I catch this exception in the method, so test is ending with error: "Expected java.lang.NullPointerException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown."

```java
class MyClass {
   void myMethod() {
        try {
            //do somthing
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            //tell about exception
        }
   }
}

class MyClassTest {  
  @Test 
  void shouldThrowNullPointerException() {
       MyClass odj = new MyClass();
       
       Assertions.assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> obj.myMethod());      
   }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assertThrows` is meant for **uncaught** exception. It makes no sense for cases where the method catches the exception. You can not test for that directly. If `//do somthing` is doing something that you can observe from outside your method, then you can assert on that (i.e. if your catch block would return `null`or some other value to signify that an error occured.

Comment: Thanks.
I edited the question a little. 
If the method catchs exception then I don't need to test this method?

Comment: At least you do not need to test for the exception.